# Place matplotlib to specific cordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to get my two graphs into the black boxes you see in this Picture.

[image]
But no matter what I try, they never arrange themselves there, as you can see here.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea where my problem is?
This is my Source code for the Graphs.

```
fig = Figure(dpi=100)
fig.set_size_inches(3.99, 2.72, forward=True)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(['Juni', 'Test', 'Yessir'], [1, 3254, 235], 
marker=mpath.Path.unit_circle(), markersize=5)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)
canvas.get_tk_widget().moveto(481, 222)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, side="left", expand=False)

abteilungen = [ 'Editing', 'Web Entwicklung', '3D Modeling', 'NFT', 'Office']
anteile = [15,25,40,10,11]

fig2 = Figure(dpi=100)
fig2.set_size_inches(3.99, 2.72, forward=True)
fig2.add_subplot(111).pie(anteile, radius=1, labels=abteilungen, autopct='%0.2f%%',)
fig2.legend()
chart1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2,master=window)
chart1.get_tk_widget().moveto(69, 222)
chart1.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, side="right", expand=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a day of trying I figured out, i dont need to place the canvas instead of packing them. So the Code is:

```
fig = Figure(dpi=100)
fig.set_size_inches(3.99, 2.72, forward=True)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(['Juni', 'Test', 'Yessir'], [1, 3254, 235], 
marker=mpath.Path.unit_circle(), markersize=5)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=481, y=222)

abteilungen = [ 'Editing', 'Web Entwicklung', '3D Modeling', 'NFT', 'Office']
anteile = [15,25,40,10,11]

fig2 = Figure(dpi=100)
fig2.set_size_inches(3.99, 2.72, forward=True)
fig2.add_subplot(111).pie(anteile, radius=1, labels=abteilungen, 
autopct='%0.2f%%',)
chart1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2,master=window)
chart1.get_tk_widget().place(x=69, y=222)
```